# Android CursorLoader SQL to display media thumbnails from an external folder

Tags: java, android-sqlite, android-cursorloader

I need to return a Cursor with ONLY media from an external folder.

I am currently returning ALL media in my phone, I just need the media in the following location

```
content://com.whereiskieran.android.spotamaster.fileprovider/root/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Spot_A_");
```

Can anyone tell me how I can create the SQL to return just this media to the Cursor Loader please?

Regards

Kieran

---

```
@Override
    public Loader <Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + albumName);
        Uri newUri = Uri.parse(file.getPath());

        String authorities = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";
        Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authorities, file);

        Uri correct = Uri.parse("content://com.whereiskieran.android.spotamaster.fileprovider/root/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Spot_A_");

        Log.d("Info", "3, Location of Spot_A_ is = " + file);
        Log.d("Info", "6, newUri is =" + newUri.toString());
        Log.d("Info", "7, myDir is =" + myDir.toString());
        Log.d("Info", "9, imageURi =" + imageUri);

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME

        };
        String where = "  _data LIKE '/Spot_A_/%'";

        //What do I add to this query to return only one external folder?
        String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE
                + " OR "
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%Spot_A_%"};

        Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

        return new CursorLoader(
                this,
                queryUri,
                projection,
                selection,  // <------This line???
                null,
                sortOrder
        );

    } //End onCreateLoader
```